# is there a way to revert a expiration date for an object in openstack swift?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

WIth openstack swift I can set a date for an object to be expired.
After this date or at this date a daemon will take care of delete the object. But if I regreat and want to cancel the expiration date, how can I do it ?

Comment: Is this question about Openstack Swift or Amazon S3?  They are different things ... so tagging your question with both is misleading.  (And tagging it with `[swift]` is even more so.  Check the tag wiki!!)

Comment: removed amazon flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/user-guide/cli-swift-set-object-expiration.html), you can cancel an expiration by removing the "X-Delete-At" header from the object:

```
$ swift post CONTAINER <OBJECT_FILENAME> -H "X-Remove-Delete-At:"
```

Obviously ... you need to do this before the object's scheduled deletion time.